# How can I reverse too many subdivisions?

Tags: vertices, sculpting, subdivision-surface

i have added too many subdivisions and do not know how to reverse these. i need help with this

[image]

this would help understand the issue

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks. (I can't edit this question for some reason?)

Answer (score 0):

i found out. you need to do to decimate and then click un sub divide

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of context here so I'll offer this...

If this was recent try loading an autosave, from the file menu.

Otherwise depending what version you are running, you could use either the remesh modifier or go into sculpt mode and use the remesh tool. However If you have topology you you wanted to keep you'll lose that.